# What's the different between iPad Retina simulator and iPad Air simulator in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode6

An iPad Air already has a Retina screen, so why has Apple deliberately designed two kinds of simulator?

Comment: But iPad mini 2(Retina) use A7(64bit) too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simulator does not include the iPad mini. The difference between the Retina and the Air is the 64 bit processor.

iPad Air = Retina x64

iPad Retina = Retina x32

iPad 2 = Non-Retina x32

To test the iPad mini Apple recommends testing on a non-retina device (aka iPad 2):

From the "Apple iOS Simulator Guide":

> Although an iPad mini isn’t an option for a simulated device in
>   Simulator, you can still test apps for the iPad mini in the simulator.
>   To do this, run your app on the simulated iPad without Retina display.

Edit:
You can also test iPad mini on iPad Retina Simulator.

See updated Apple "[iOS Simulator User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html)":

> Testing for the iPad mini
>   To test apps for the iPad mini in the simulator, run your app on a simulated 
>   iPad with the corresponding type of display, either Retina or non-Retina 
>   depending on the iPad mini model.